# Does the scale of C major with a half-sharp D have a name?

Tags: theory, scales, terminology, microtonality

[image: C, D-semisharp, E, F, G, A, B, C]

I am using the same melody for 2 instruments and I half-sharpened every D note on the second one, and left the first as C major. Does this have a name? Or is it used anywhere?

Comment: That sign is unusual. Is it supposed to mean a *semitone* sharp, or *half a semitone* (*quarter tone*) sharp? Can understand D# being played, but not the other.

Comment: @Tim it looks to me like the standard half-sharp sign (like a normal sharp sign but with only one vertical stroke) that was cropped from a full staff, so it retains short segments of the horizontal staff lines.  Those should have been removed.

Comment: It’s a cropped standard half-sharp. First instrument is piano, and second is violin where micro tonalities are easy to play

Answer (score 1):

A scale that comes close to it is mentioned as a vertex tetrachord but it is not exactly a D with 50 cents but a D+33 cents and an additional A+33 cents: https://mizzan.de/archive/src/scala/vertex_diat2.html. If you are interested in microtonality you could drill here https://mizzan.de/scales

Comment: Should it be D half-sharp or both D and A half-sharp?

Comment: Both, expressed in cents: 0, 233, 400, 500, 700, 933, 1100. However, you are free to do whatever you like and choose the material that fits best your musical ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a particular context for it... it seems like a scale base on microtonal ancient music.

Anyway, you could find something like that in ethnic music, Indian music in particular where you can find hundreds of scales like that.
You can hear a lot of this also in Arabic music.